# Angularjs - issue with json : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to delete an object from an array with Angularjs Resource:

```
CommandeDetail.delete({id:commandeDetail.id});
```

My factory :

```
.factory('CommandeDetail', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/commandeDetail/:id', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET'
            }
        });
    })
```

My object commandeDetail is (debug on Chrome before delete is called) :

> commandeDetail: Resource
>   $$hashKey: "object:1136"
>   calibre: "douze"
>   categorie: "II"
>   certificatFournisseur: "AGROCERT"
>   commande: null
>   commandeId: 10
>   commentaire: null
>   dispJ4: 0
>   emballage: "COLIS 10 KG NET"
>   id: 35
>   marque: "ECOCERT"
>   max: 10
>   nbPalettes: 0
>   produit: "ABRICOT"
>   puht: 0
>   quantite: 10
>   tare: 0
>   valorisation: "Net"

The delete is well done on server side but I am getting this error on frontSide :

```
angular.js:11598 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at join (native)
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at toJson (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1048:15)
    at defaults.defaults.transformRequest (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8707:74)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8655:12
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at transformData (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8654:3)
    at $get.serverRequest (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9319:23)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13175:27)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13191:27
```

I don't know where that can come from. My object is quite simple.
If anybody can help me on this...
Thanks

Comment: "Maximum call stack size exceeded" points towards endless loop using recursion. As this call happens due to Object.stringify (second "at" in callstack) angular tries to json-ify (convert a js object into json string) that contains end loop/circular dependency.

Comment: I agree, but my object contains simple properties, that's why I don't understand.

Comment: Try to debug into transformRequest function and investigate which object angular tries to stringify.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need absolute path in rest id: '/api/commandeDetail/:id'